py-click isn't responding with the function in python
Here is my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="light">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ScratchFind</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.4.1/core.css">
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.4.1/core.js"></script>
    <script type="py" src="./main.py" config="./pyscript.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Back end -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Front end -->
    <h1>ScratchFind</h1>
    <input id="url" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Paste your URL here">
    <input py-click="hello" type="submit" value="Find!">
    <h1 id="display"></h1>
    
    <!-- Theme toggle -->
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleTheme()">
        <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>

</body>
</html>

and here is my python code:
import requests
from pyscript import document

url = document.querySelector("#url")
display = document.querySelector("#display")
display.innerText = "a"
link = ""

def hello():
  link = url.value
  display.innerText = link

main.py is working but the function isn't called when I click the button.
I am expecting that when the button is pressed the code inside the function hello works.

When I try your code, I see an error:
TypeError: hello() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

When using the py-*event syntax, the function is passed an Event object corresponding to the triggering event. You can either receive this event and use it (def hello(evt):) or swallow and ignore it (def hello(*args)).
